# What would happen if entity model has relations but data (views) in database doesn't have relations and if they are inconsistent?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My question is would Spring JPA throw exceptions for every query?

I mean, let say there are tables without any relation (FK) between them in database. It is bad design but you cannot change it and it is not up to you.

But you know that data itself should be as there are relations.

That's why you create Entity model with all relations like they are there.

But as I said there is no real relations in database.

And in one point data are inconsistent in database.

Would Spring JPA throw exceptions if there are inconsistency or it will just return you inconsistent data?

Answer (score 0):

I assume with "relations" you mean "foreign keys".

JPA doesn't care about foreign keys.
All it cares about is if the data matches the mapping information on the entities.

So if you have an entity `A` that references an entity `B` with id `b` but such a `B` does not exist you might eventually get an exception. 
Or you might just get an `A` with a null reference to `B`.
If the reference is marked as mandatory you might actually not be able to load the `A` in the first place, because a join is used and therefore not returning any data at all.

Side note: All this depends more on the JPA implementation you are using than on Spring Data JPA.

Comment: If you have OneToMany, and query returns more than One, would I have exception or I will have more than one objects related to it or I will have first one?

Comment: If you have a OneToMany I think you normally already have the one side, so most of the time probably not a problem here. The other direction: ManyToOne and the one side turns out to be multiple entities. This is going to cause problems. Hard to tell which one exactly. Also note this is not just a lack of foreign keys but a primary key missing.